# an issue with shields in minecraft 1.14.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

ive seen some videos of it, it may be a mod or something. but it looks like the person's shield only comes out when they have their sword equipped, i havent figured out how to do that. can someone tell me how they managed to do that?

Comment: Are you playing on a multiplayer server? Some have weird mods that could cause this.

Comment: yes im playing on a multiplayer server, but ive seen streams of people doing stuff like this

Comment: @Carl, Can you link a video or something? Are they also playing on a server?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is either a mod or a plugin for the sever itself. (Or, even from an hacked client, although I haven't found one that claims to do this)

Plugins i've found to do this are:

- [OldCombatMechanics](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/oldcombatmechanics-disable-1-9-hit-cooldown.19510/)
- [ProtocolSupportStuff](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/protocolsupportstuff.44527/)
- [Better Combat](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/better-combat.19439/)

Comment: It's important to know that all these mods are fundamentally flawed. Different Minecraft versions are not meant to play with each other and there are many good reasons for that. This sword/shield issue is one of the least bad ones.